# ROS2 Run __params not affecting node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm running on D and E, neither can I get my read in parameter file to affect the node, ei

```
ros2 run slam_toolbox localization_slam_toolbox_node __params:=install/slam_toolbox/share/config/mapper_params_localization.yaml
```

and a more simple example:

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp parameter_blackboard __params:=install/slam_toolbox/share/config/mapper_params_localization.yaml
```

For the blackboard example I directly copied the example from the tutorials page into that config file:

```
parameter_blackboard:
    ros__parameters:
        some_int: 42
        a_string: "Hello world"
        some_lists:
            some_integers: [1, 2, 3, 4]
            some_doubles : [3.14, 2.718]
```

and for the slam_toolbox example, a simple minimum look at a single parameter:

```
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:
    solver_plugin: blahblah::FakePluginFailToLoadPlz
```

When I run the blackboard demo, it crashes if I give it a bad file path, but my node doesnt, but still fails to have anything from it included.

Any thoughts? It seems like none of the ROS2 nodes I have will accept any comandline params, but when I do

```
__ns:='/hi'
```

on the blackboard, that will take fine. My other node again produces no errors even if this namespace is invalid and just doesn't take.

I am declaring my parameters:

```
  std::string solver_plugin = std::string("solver_plugins::CeresSolver");
  solver_plugin = this->declare_parameter("solver_plugin", solver_plugin);
```

Edit:

I'm seeing though the 1 random param in blackboard (use_sim_time, with all nodes) will work if I set it in the file, but not reading the others in the file at all.
https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/parameter_blackboard.cpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335016/ros2-run-__params-not-affecting-node/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Huh, after a full day on this, I cleaned up paths and tried again and started working. Can't really explain why, maybe something got cached in an odd state. Closing

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0